# twinmain in c++ Console application?

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, win32gui

Currently I'm working on this example 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx
that helped me capture any changes in my hardware. (Like connecting and disconnecting a USB flash drive)

The sample explains that in order to enable my console project to compile this code I had to set Project->Properties->Linker->System->Subsystem to Windows

My main problem is that I require the project to stay like a console application.
Is there any way to run this code by a console application or shall I be using a whole new strategy?

Thanks

Comment: The only 2 differences between a console application and a GUI application are: `1` A console application has a console window attached to it when it is launched, and `2` the entry point signature is different (when using the CRT): `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. You can do anything in a console application you can do in a GUI application.

Comment: And, in fact, you can change the `SUBSYSTEM` type for an application after the fact with `editbin`.